# Assigning Functions using <- or ->

Tags: r

I've been searching around google and not yielding much describing the difference in behaviour of <- and -> aside from the former being assignment and the latter more akin to a pipe. I'm curious why

```
f <- function() {1+1}
```

will assign a function to f in the namespace. However,

```
function() {1+1} -> f
```

Does not and instead simply returns the function to stdout. Is there a resource out there that describes the differences in behaviour described here?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a result of how R is parsing the expression. If you do `{function() {1+1}} -> f` the right assignment works. Without the extra braces, I don't think R knows that `-> f` isn't supposed to be part of the function body too.

Comment: Yes have a look at chapter 2 of Advanced R. It goes into detail about the nitty gritty of assignment operators in R. See: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html

Comment: The parser interprets your line as `function() { {1+1) -> x }`, i.e. the assignment is part of the function body. If you intend to store a function this way then firstly _don't_, and secondly wrap the function in either curly braces or parentheses.

Comment: could someone please post one of these comments as an answer?

Comment: Just to be clear: *both* of these are (semantically completely identical!) assignments. In fact, `->` is transformed by the R parser into `<-`. Try it yourself: `quote(1 -> a)`. `->` is *in no way* “akin to a pipe”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The consensus from the comments above is that the parser is interpreting

```
function() {1+1} -> f
```

as:

```
function() { {1+1) -> x }
```

and so it merely echoes that function at the console. You have to be more explicit about the grouping, e.g.

```
{function() {1+1}} -> f
```

so it is clear to the parser what is being assigned to `f`.